# Linking DLL to project doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, dll, linker

I created a DLL project called Test Lib:

```
// main.h
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" {
    DLL_EXPORT void print();
}
#endif

// main.cpp
#define BUILD_DLL

#include "main.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

extern "C" {
    DLL_EXPORT void print() {
        cout << "Success" << endl;

        return;
    }
}
```

The library builds successfuly, and I then created a console project called TestApp:

```
// main.cpp
#include <main.h>

int main() {
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

Test Lib and TestApp folders are both in C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Practice Projects

On Code::Blocks -> Global compiler settings -> Search directories,

- Compiler has added C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Practice Projects\Test Lib
- Linker has added C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Practice Projects\Test Lib\bin\Debug

In TestApp -> Build options -> Linker settings, Link libraries has added Linker has added C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Practice Projects\Test Lib\bin\Debug\libTest Lib.dll.a

When I try to run the program, I get "TestApp.exe - Unable to Locate Component"

> This application has failed to start because Test Lib.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem.

`main()` returns `0xC0000135`. This is the second DLL library I have ever created, and is because I encountered the same error in my first library and I am trying to replicate the error.

In one attempt, I tried to change the .dll.a link to a relative path. In another attempt, I moved the compiler and linker directories down to project-level rather than global level, all three paths in absolute format. In a third attempt, I did the same but with all three paths in relative format. None of these work, and give the same error.

What's going wrong?

Edit: Someone said in comments I need to add the DLL path to system settings. I don't understand what I need to do when he says that. I was following [this tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855/DLL-Tutorial-For-Beginners.htm) on creating and using DLL, which says I needed to add the .lib and .dll to the project path, which is what I did as described above after doing more searching (Code::Blocks isn't my usual IDE, my employer gave it to me for temporary use). When I created my first DLL 2 days ago, that was all I did and everything worked. Then, I added a new function for checking if an integer is a prime. Yesterday morning, I came back to work and the DLL doesn't work anymore. I have been trying to figure out the problem until now, because I had not done anything to cause it to stop working (I literally only added the function, turned the computer, left work and returned the next day, then rebuild the DLL project and ran the console app project). Now, I tried searching on how to add a DLL path to system settings, and I don't see any results relevant to C++ and/or Code::Blocks that looks like the answer. Can someone tell me what I'm supposed to be looking for?

Comment: Did you already try to add the DLLs containing directory to your systems `PATH` variable?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How do I do that? I don't think I did, because in my first library, I only did what I said and it worked, then I added a new function and the next day when I came back and booted up the laptop, it no longer work. The new function just checks whether the variable given is a prime, so I don't see how it affects anything. I have already added the directory paths as stated above.

Comment: You add that directory to your environments `PATH` variable as mentioned? It's done via system settings (not compiler options).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So how do I do that, where are the system settings? I've been searching for a solution all day yesterday and I couldn't find anything on Google that I could understand and follow

Comment: C'mon you can't navigate to your computers  `system settings->environment variables`? Really?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't know where that is. I have never needed to change my computer's system settings/registry/etc. for programming before. Like I said, this is my first time creating libraries. And I'm working in an IDE, not on command prompt.

Comment: That's a system setting, sorry I'm not at a windows system to get the necessary steps to nannying you there. There's no need for the command prompt IIRC.

Comment: Changing the system PATH to fix the problem is the wong solution.  The Testlib.dll file needs to be in the same folder as the TestApp.exe.  This is normally handled by VS if both the DLL and EXE are in the same solution when the "output directories" property for the linker is set up right.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm is it possible not to be in the same folder? My DLL is intended to be used for multiple projects.

Comment: Then you either need to _install_ the DLL so it will be some place windows can find it, change the PATH environment variable to point to where your DLL is (which leads to PATH bloat and potential future problems), or load your DLL dynamically with LoadLibrary when you can specify the path to it.  The simplest solution is to have a copy of your DLL in the same folder as the EXE.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm _" 
Changing the system PATH to fix the problem is the wong solution."_ and advising so in the next comment is??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not advising it; I'm just listing it as one way to accomplish what OP is trying to do while attempting to discourage its use.